# How to execute a batch script in resources folder of Electron app packaged with electron-builder

Tags: node.js, batch-file, electron

I have successfully built an electron app built with react. I packaged the app with a batch script in the resources folder under a server subdirectory. Wrote a `script.js` file and included that in the startup of the electron app. In turn, the `script.js` file calls a batch script that's in the same directory as the batch file.

Below is the `script.js` file

```js
const { Notification } = require('electron');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const setup = async () => {
    const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'setup.bat']);
    bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
    
    bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        notify({title: 'Build Server Error', body: data.toString()})
        console.error(data.toString());
    });
    
    bat.on('exit', (code) => {
        console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
    });
}

const notify = ({title, body})=> {
  new Notification({ title, body}).show()
}

module.exports = { setup };
```

This is my project structure

[image: project structure]

This is the file path after installation

[image: File path after intallation]

This is how I am importing the `setup.js` in the `windowActions.js`

```js
const {setup} = require(path.join(app.getAppPath(), "../server/setup.js"));

// This is how i invoke the setup function
const buildServer = async () => {
    try {
        await setup();
    } catch (err) {
        notify({title: 'Build Server Catch Error', body: err.message})
    }
}
```

The Notifier gets called with the error `setup.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Executing the `script.js` outside of electron works perfectly.

I have tried using the path helper function in node but it threw `file://` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

I appreciate every contribution.

Comment: As you've not included anything in your submission which specifies the current working directory. You have also not submitted the content of your `setup.bat` file. Additionally we have no idea if your script is being run as x64 or x86, or what architecture the end user Operating System is using. It would be useful if you could also try to obtain a little more debugging information.

Comment: it's executed as x64 and I submitted images of the directories for the setup.js and setup.bat they are both in the same directory

Comment: I didn't submit the setup.bat because that isn't throwing any errors the setup.bat doesn't get executed at all. It is not even considered as a batch file. I specified the error I got in return: `setup.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: I'll reiterate my main point again Limitless Claver. What is the current directory at the time your `setup.js` file is being run? I would advise that your `setup.js` file includes a function to reference its own location, then use that to prepend that to `setup.bat`.